# Problems with Login application in struts2

Tags: struts2, actioncontext

I am trying to write small login application in struts 2.Session is b eing created successfully.In welcome.jsp "logout" option is given.On logout control will be  redirected to Logout.jsp.
                   My problem is after logout session variables are destroyed but pages are storing in browser cache.If click back button of browser i am able to see welcome.jsp.
For clearing cache "ClearCacheInterceptor" is used.I don't understand where i am making mistake.
                   Instead of clearing browser every time is there any to overcome this prooblem ? Is my approach correct ? Please suggest me.

Login.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib  uri="/struts-tags"  prefix="s"  %>    
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <s:form action="login">
        <s:textfield name="myname"></s:textfield>
        <s:submit value="submit"></s:submit>
    </s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Struts.xml

```
<interceptors>
            <interceptor name="clear-cache"  class="ActionClasses.ClearCacheInterceptor" />
         </interceptors>

        <action name="login" class="ActionClasses.LoginAction" >
           <interceptor-ref name="clear-cache" /> 
           <result name="success">Welcome.jsp</result>
           <result name="error">Login.jsp</result>
        </action>  

        <action name="logout" class="ActionClasses.Logout">
          <interceptor-ref name="clear-cache" /> 
          <result name="success">Logout.jsp</result>
        </action>
```

LoginAction.java

```
package ActionClasses;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.SessionAware;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.annotations.RequiredFieldValidator;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.annotations.ValidatorType;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.apache.struts2.ServletActionContext;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionInvocation;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.Interceptor;

public class LoginAction extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware
{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String myname;
    private Map<String , Object> s;

    public String execute()throws Exception
    {

            s=ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
            s.put("login", myname);

         return "success";

   }


    public void setMyname(String s)
    {

        myname=s;

    }

    public String getMyname()
    {
        return myname;
    }


    @Override
    public void setSession(Map<String, Object> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        s=arg0;
    }
  }
```

ClearcacheInterceptor.java

```
package ActionClasses;





import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.struts2.StrutsStatics;



import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionInvocation;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor;



public class ClearCacheInterceptor  extends AbstractInterceptor{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override

    public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {

        ActionContext context=(ActionContext)invocation.getInvocationContext();

        HttpServletResponse response=(HttpServletResponse)context.get(StrutsStatics.HTTP_RESPONSE);

        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

        response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");

        response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);

        String result=invocation.invoke();

        System.out.println("check result="+result);

        return result;

    }

}
```

Logout.java

```
package ActionClasses;

import java.util.Map;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;


public class Logout extends ActionSupport  {



    public String execute(){

        Map<String,Object> s=ActionContext.getContext().getSession();



        s.remove("login");



        ActionContext.getContext().getSession().clear();



        return "success";
    }



}
```

Welcome.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<s:include value="CheckLogin.jsp"></s:include>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<font color="white"></font>
Welcome<s:property value="#session['login']"/>
<s:a href="logout">Logout</s:a>
</body>
</html>
```

Logout.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

log out successful !!


</body>
</html>
```

CheckLogin.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html" import="java.util.*"%>
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Check validate!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  This is session validation page!

  <s:if test="#session.login != 'Jagan'">
  <jsp:forward page="Login.jsp" />  
  </s:if>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems something wrong with interceptor in struts.xml.

Comment: Removes session cookies  on logout could be another solution rather deleting caches every time but i don't know how to do that.

Comment: try adding `response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");` in your interceptor

Comment: @anu: It doesn't work with all browsers.I am looking for  browser independent solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well that's a very common issue and this is with respect to your browser cache issue rather than struts2 or any other framework at all.

we have face same problem since when you hit the back button of browser the request is not being send to the server rather it is being serves from the browser cache.you will only notice things when you try to do some work and it will come up with error that you are no longer being logged in.

though you can use certain header like no-cache etc but they are being obeyed by the browser is not certain.
only workaround to this problem as per my understanding is to use https (secure browsing) for your work and than use the header (no-cache. cache-expiry etc) since when you browse application under secure mode these header will be followed by the server and browser.

i hope this will try to give you an idea, just to check redirect to https protocol when your logout and it will solve your problem

Comment: How to do that (redirecting ot https protocol)? Please provide me any useful link.

Comment: use struts2 plugin for this here is the URL for same   http://code.google.com/p/struts2-ssl-plugin/